# Is there any interpreter that works well for running multiprocessing in python 2.7 version on windows 7?

Tags: python, windows-7, multiprocessing, command-prompt, interpreter

I was trying to run a piece of code.This code is all about multiprocessing.It works fine on command prompt and it also generates some output.But when I try to run this code on pyscripter it just says that script runs ok and it doesn't generate any output nor even it displays any error message.It doesn't even crashes.It would be really helpful if anyone could help me out to find out a right interpreter where this multiprocessing works fine.
Here is the piece of code:

```
    from multiprocessing import Process
    def wait():
        print "wait"
        clean()
   def clean():
        print "clean"
   def main():
        p=Process(target=wait)
        p.start()
        p.join()
   if _name_=='_main_':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal interpreter works just fine with `multiprocessing` on Windows 7 for me. (Your IDE might not like multiprocessing.)

You just have to do

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

with 2 underscores (`__`) each instead of 1 (`_`).

Also - if you don't have an actual reason not to use it, `multiprocessing.Pool` is much easier to use than `multiprocessing.Process` in most cases. Have alook at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

An implementation with a Pool would be

```
import multiprocessing
def wait():
    print "wait"
    clean()
def clean():
    print "clean"
def main():
    p=multiprocessing.Pool()
    p.apply_async(wait)
    p.close()
    p.join()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

but which method of Pool to use strongly depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am using 2 underscores and it is not working on pyscripter.May I know what interpreter you are using?

Comment: Will you please provide multiprocessing using pool with the code that I have mentioned above?

Comment: Thank you but my interpreter even doesn't print any statement eventhough if I use pool

Comment: Can you please mention the name of interpreter that you are using

Comment: `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` (same results with `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`) but there is no printed output visible (propably because IDLE only watches the main process) when running in IDLE - you have to run via command line

Comment: But I need to use interpreter only.Will you please suggest an interpreter?Or do you have an alternate solution?

Comment: I was saying that the program runs well on the normal Python 2.7 interpreters for Windows (both 32 bit and 64 bit) that you can get on https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ but due to the way IDLE works you cannot see printed output from different processes in it so you have to open the console (cmd.exe) and run the program there. you can also put a 'raw_input()' after 'main()' so the program does not terminate directly and run it by double-clicking the file

Comment: If not print statement atleast it should perform some operations right.It is not even performing any operation.How do I know whether it is calling wait and clean functions properly or not?

Comment: you could create files which you can view later. eg `open("wait_works.yay","w")` instead of `print "wait"`

Comment: Will you elaborate it in detail please?

Comment: If the function `open("wait_works.yay","w")` gets called in your program, then an empty file called `wait_works.yay` is created in the directory where you run the program. This is visible inedependently of whether you can see console output or not.

Comment: Thanks,I have another problem now.I am trying to link this multiprocessing script to an GUI.The sole purpose of the script is when we run this script in the background,based on the operations that we perform on gui script should perform the corresponding operation ,but as soon as I ran this python script everything freezes and I can't even control gui.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If you are just want to uncouple gui from calculations, you should better use threads as their usage is much simpler. If you don't want to change all your code, just use [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) instead of `multiprocessing` (eg `import multiprocessing.dummy as multiprocessing`)

Comment: will you please show an example with threading where input is given through gui.I am new to python programming.Sorry for asking too much of help

Comment: Sorry, that strongly depends on what gui you use and what exactly you want to do - try without threading, post a new question and i will have a look at it (also i cannot post large chunks of code in the comments - like here)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835662/how-to-avoid-freezing-of-gui-while-linking-python-muliprocessing-script-linked-t