# How to avoid freezing of GUI while linking python muliprocessing script linked to a gui (python script should run in background)

Tags: python, user-interface, background, multiprocessing, freeze

I have python script linked to gui and which runs in background.Based on the input from the GUI the python script should send messages accordingly.But as soon as I link my script( where I am using multiprocessing) to GUI,Screen freezes.Is there anything that I am doing wrong?Please provide me a solution.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
slider_perc= [0.0 ,10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0,50,60.0,70.0,80.0,90.0,100]           
slider_output_msg=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]

Slider_dictionary=dict(zip(slider_perc,slider_output_msg))
def change_slider():
    slider_pos=myAppl.Variable(slider).Read()
    slider_pos_round=int(round(slider_pos,-1))

    Desired_slider_Position=dict((k,Slider_dictionary[k]) for k in  [slider_pos_round] if k in Slider_dictionary)
    Desired_slider_Message=Desired_slider_Position.values()
    TxMessage_out=Desired_slider_Message
    status = vt.GetMessageResponse(TxMessage_out,RxPattern,Timeout,Flag)
def main():
    p = Process(target=change_slider())
    p.start()
    p.join()
main()
```

Comment: On windows you need `if __name__=="__main__":` to avoid hanging. Have a look at the [Guidlines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) - especially [those for Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)

Comment: eventhough i use that screen is hanging

Comment: The call to `p.join()` will block until the process completes. If you want it to run in the background, you'll have to drop that call.

Comment: Try replacing `from multiprocessing import Process` with `from multiprocessing.dummy import Process` (which actually uses threads) to see if using multiple processes is causing the problem.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem

Comment: I get can't pickle the function error if I remove p.join() statement from  my code

Comment: You have an extra pair of parens in the constructor to Process. It should read `p = Process(target=change_slider)`

Comment: if I don't use those extra parenthesis then it doesn't even start the process.That's what I have observed.Will you please suggest me an method to make this code working in background without freezing the screen?

Comment: how to make gui work on one process and my slider function to work on different process?

Comment: The extra parens cause the code to actually call the `change_slider` function and assign the result (`None` in this case) to the keyword argument `target`. That's probably the cause of your pickle error, since it's trying to pickle `None`. I have some real concerns about the design of your code. It looks like you're trying to change values of variables inside your GUI from your new process, which I'm pretty sure is not going to work very well. There are variables in your code that are not defined; where do `myAppl` and `vt` come from? Can you revise your question to show what you're doing?

Comment: If you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verfiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we might be able to help better.

Comment: I can't provide you those variables hope you understand.Will you please let me know why my screen freezes as soon as I link my script.The code works fine with all those variables.I just want to get rid of screen freezing.